# Unit Testing Flux.doOnNext()

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a method which takes a Flux as a parameter.  Inside the method it then configures the Flux and another method subscribes to it.

```
public class StringProcessor {

  private final stringParsingService stringParsingService;

  public void subscribeStringFlux(Flux<String> stringFlux) {
    fluxConfiguration(stringFlux)
        .subscribe();
  }

  Flux<String> fluxConfiguration(Flux<String> stringFlux) {
    return stringFlux
        .filter(stringValidatorr::isValidString)
        .doOnNext(itemString -> {
          List<String> values = stringParsingService.parseValues(itemString);
        })
        .onErrorContinue((e,object) -> log.error(e.getClass().toString()+" "+e.getMessage()));
  }
}
```

I am trying to test that the code in doOnNext is executed.  I've tried to use StepVerifier (with Mockito for the service) however it never seems to enter the code during the test when I put breakpoints in stringParsingService.parseValue().  However, the code does run and execute as expected though when not being run in a test with real data.

My question is, how do you write tests that cover actions taken in a Flux.doOnNext()?  Is there a way to use StepVerifier that will get it to execute code in doOnNext()? I've searched for days, and tried multiple approaches and so far none of them have worked.

The only way I've found so far that even comes close is to do the following (however this of course doesn't count for code coverage):

```
    Flux<String> testStringFlux = Flux.just("a_test_string");

    StepVerifier.create(testStringFlux)
        .consumeNextWith(itemString -> {
           List<String> values = stringParsingService.parseValues(itemString);
        })
        .verifyComplete();
```

Comment: You create a test string, you call your function with that test string. The function returns a flux. You run that flux in the StepVerifier och step through and assert the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doOnNext` is a side-effet operator, meaning that the work it performs isn't really visible from the perspective of the main reactive sequence (the `Flux<T>`). As a result, none of the tools that are used to test a `Flux` can really see and test the side-effect, unless YOU make it testable explicitly.

One possible way would be to make the `StringProcessor.stringParsingService` used in your test a mock, or a test-specific instance that records parsed strings, and then assert that at the end of the `Flux` sequence.

Note that your `doOnNext` computes a `List`, but that list isn't used after that. The elements emitted by `someFlux.doOnNext(function)` are exactly the same as the ones emitted by `someFlux`, independently of what is done inside the `function` (unless the `function` throws, but that's a different story).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  It seems odd to me that sideffects aren't testable, and kind of a blindspot in the functionality of StepVerifier.

Comment: it's akin to saying "I want to test the Runnable effect  of a `ExecutorService.submit(Runnable)`", if you want a point of comparison with a JDK class.

Answer (score 0):

if you configure your flux as follows, it will stop at a breakpoint on the parseValues function. But I am not sure if this is what you are asking for...

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>flux_test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

StringProcessor.java

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class StringProcessor {

    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(StringProcessor.class.getName());

    private class StringParsingService {
        List<String> parseValues(String str) {
            return Arrays.asList(str.split(","));
        }
    }

    private static class StringValidator {
        static boolean isValidString(String str) {
            return str.length() > 1;
        }
    }

    private final StringParsingService stringParsingService = new StringParsingService();

    public void subscribeStringFlux(Flux<String> stringFlux) {
        fluxConfiguration(stringFlux)
                .subscribe();
    }

    Flux<String> fluxConfiguration(Flux<String> stringFlux) {
        return stringFlux
                .filter(StringValidator::isValidString)
                .doOnNext(itemString -> {
                    List<String> values = stringParsingService.parseValues(itemString);
                })
                .onErrorContinue((e, object) -> log.error(e.getClass().toString() + " " + e.getMessage()));
    }

}
```

TestFlux.java

```
import org.junit.Test;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;
import reactor.test.publisher.TestPublisher;

public class TestFlux {

    final TestPublisher<String> testPublisher = TestPublisher.create();

    @Test
    public void testFlux() {
        StepVerifier.create(new StringProcessor().fluxConfiguration(testPublisher.flux()))
                .then(() -> testPublisher.emit("aa,bb", "cc,dd"))
                .expectNext("aa,bb")
                .expectNext("cc,dd")
                .verifyComplete();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, when I run the test the way you wrote just emitting the first String and only one expectNext("aa,bb") I get an Assertion error "expected: onNext("aa,bb") actual: onComplete()".  I am using Junit 5, but otherwise my setup is troughly the same as your pom (I'm using Spring Boot's reactor).  Also, yes, I want to be able to hit a breakpoint in the parseValues method during test.

Comment: If you would like to emit and expect only one item, you can change the emmitter to testPublisher.emit("aa,bb") , then it will succeed. Both ways, you should be able to use breakpoints if you start tests in debug mode...